# Canvas is drawing rectangle bigger than my dimension

Tags: php, html, css, canvas, draw

I am working with a .php file where I want to draw in a canvas some rectangles. I think I am using them correctly but the scale is wrong for some reason.

I have here a div with a canvas that is `450px*750px`:

```
echo '<h2><strong>Supermarket</strong> Map</h2>';
echo '<div class="wrapper_map" style="width: 750px; height: 450px; position:relative; margin: 0 auto;"><canvas id="myCanvas" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></canvas></div>';
```

And I want to draw a rectangle that is on the top left corner with `width 150px` and `height 150px`, which is basically a square.

I use this code to do it:

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");';
echo 'var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");';

echo 'ctx.fillStyle = "' . $color . '";';
echo 'ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,150);';
echo '</script>';
```

I suppose that I should be getting correct results, although I get a rectangle with random dimensions:

[image: Size of canvas]

[image: Drawn rectangle]

As we can see in the photos the dimensions of the canvas are correct, however the rectangle is much bigger than `150px*150px`.

Anyone knows any way to fix this?

Comment: _"As we can see in the photos the dimensions of the canvas are correct"_ - yes, and no. The canvas is getting _displayed_ at 750 * 450px size, because you specified those dimensions via CSS. A canvas has actual width and height _attributes_ though, that determine how many pixels it contains. You did not explicitly specify those, so your canvas has a default width of 300px, and a default height of 150px. And those dimensions are not getting _stretched_, when you make the canvas _display_ at a different size using CSS.

Comment: You need to explicitly specify your canvas' width and height as 450px and 750px respectively. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas#attributes

Comment: (_"And those dimensions are not getting stretched"_ - that "not" should have been "now", comment too old to edit already.)

Answer (score 0):

The canvas need to be edited like this:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="750"; height="450"; style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;"></canvas>
```

By declaring the width and the height I am making sure that there won't be any changes to the size of the canvas